# how to set an icon in title bar including with name of the app

Tags: android, xml, manifest

how to set an icon in title bar including with name of the app

here it looks like

[but, I need to add an icon before Sample Text in title 
please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R84JM.png)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/coffee_cup"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/coffee_cup"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PopUpActivivty"></activity>
</application>
```

no use
is there any dependencies if so tell me, please

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer is very simple no need of XML code
it's a matter of 3 lines of java code in MainActivity,

import this line inside MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

inside Create Method

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.icon_launcher);
```

Comment: to hide title
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //optional

Comment: I get the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setIcon(int)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to accomplish

If you want to change it in code, call:

```
setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

And set the values to whatever you want.

Or, in the Android manifest XML file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
       android:label="My new title" />
```

Try this. It should work

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout to show what you have in the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="394dp"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Instead use this to change the text and the icon of the action bar:

```
    getActionBar().setTitle("Title");
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sample");

    ..........
    ........................
}
```